# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty does not contain a definition for forename

Tags: c#, json, oop, json.net

I am extracting data from the following JSON

```
string strResponse =
@"[
    {
        'forename': 'Harry',
        'surname': 'Potter',
        'house': 'Gryffindor'
    },
    {
        'forename': 'Draco',
        'surname': 'Malfoy',
        'house': 'Slytherin'
    },
    {
        'forename': 'Luna',
        'surname': 'Lovegood',
        'house': 'Ravenclaw'
    }
]";
```

The C# I am using is as follows:

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponse);
foreach (var item in dynJson)
{
    string output = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.forename, item.surname, item.house);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

This works fine and the output is as expected.

However, when the JSON is in a slightly different format such as:

```
string strResponse =
@"{
    'People': [
    {
        'forename': 'Harry',
        'surname': 'Potter',
        'house': 'Gryffindor'
    },
    {
        'forename': 'Draco',
        'surname': 'Malfoy',
        'house': 'Slytherin'
    },
    {
        'forename': 'Luna',
        'surname': 'Lovegood',
        'house': 'Ravenclaw'
    }
    ]
}";
```

I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not
>   contain a definition for 'forename'

I know this is to do with the structure of the new JSON string and in particular the `People` section. But I do not know how to adapt my code to handle this, please help.

Comment: Why would you expect different JSON to behave the same way? The first is an array of objects with the properties you expect, the second is an object with a `People` property that contains an array of objects as before.

Comment: @DavidG Apologies, I am trying to learn this by building up from a simple example (first JSON) and refactoring my code to see what i would need to change for other JSON strings. I have seen JSON displayed in the format as in the second JSON string and wanted to work out how i needed to change my code.

Comment: The best way is to avoid using dynamic completely, every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies... Instead create a set of concrete C# classes that match your structure. That way you have strong, compile-time type checking. In Visual Studio, copy the JSON, then go into the edit/paste special menu and paste JSON as classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example

```
JObject dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponse) as JObject;
dynJson.Dump();
foreach (var item in dynJson["People"])
{
    string output = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item["forename"], item["surname"], item["house"]);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```